# Respond with correct syntax on error in PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I use PowerShell 5.1 and write scripts for other admins to use. I need to be able to respond with the correct syntax in the error code when the wrong syntax is used from my function. How do I do that?

```
function Get-2008Servers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$ReferenceDomain = ""
    )

    $ForestObj = Get-ADForest -Server $ReferenceDomain
    foreach ($Domain in $ForestObj.Domains) {
        Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "*200*"' -Server $ReferenceDomain -Properties Name,lastlogondate,operatingsystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,canonicalname |
            select Name,lastlogondate,operatingsystem,OperatingSystemServicePack,canonicalname |
            sort name -Descending |
            Export-Csv -Force -NoTypeInformation .\output\$ReferenceDomain-NOT2016Servers.csv
    }
}
$result = ls .\output\*-NOT2016Servers.csv
$result
```

When your run the function:

```
Get-2008Servers
```

You need to be prompted to add "-ReferenceDomain" when you try to run without the required option. How do I write that into the above code?

Answer (score 6):

By adding a `[Parameter()]` attribute decorator and specifying the `Mandatory` property:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$ReferenceDomain
)
```

Please see the [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6#mandatory-argument) for more on the `Parameter` attribute and `Mandatory`

Comment: Very nice, thank you:                                                                                                 
     PS C:\scripts> Get-2008Servers
cmdlet Get-2008Servers at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ReferenceDomain: